# JQuery Slider alternative?

Tags: jquery, html, slider

I am using the JQuery [Slider](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider) control for use as a double sided slider.

It's a great UI control but I'm looking for an alternative that isn't so "fat".

Right now, just for me to use the Slider control, I have to include:

- JQuery core
- JQuery UI core
- JQuery Slider plugin

When I both minimize using Google's awesome Closure (minimizer) and GZIP the JavaScript, I'm still at around **29kb**.

Do a comparable Slider control exist that isn't such a large download?

Answer (score 11):

I recommend [noUISlider](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/), cross browser support (including touch devices) and at only 6KB minimized.

Comment: Find a better license.

Comment: @StefanKendall it appears to be MIT now.

Answer (score 1):

checkout jquery scrollable if it can help

Answer (score 0):

I used [this](http://programming.arantius.com/lightweight+javascript+slider+control) a while back, it's ~5kb ungziped + unClosure'd - and it works well.

Comment: @blake, that looks awesome. I should have mentioned that I'm actually using the Slider as a double-handle slider. Does this work like that as well?

Comment: @AndyB I don't think so unfortunately, I think becuase that's quite niche you'd have to go for a large JS libary, sorry. Or you could build one yourself ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is the Ajax Control Toolkit...

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/Slider/Slider.aspx