# slider better than jquery ui slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, uislider, jquery-ui-slider

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JQuery Slider alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693721/jquery-slider-alternative)

Is there a better slider than jquery UI Slider?

I don't want to add too much files to my js directory for just a single slider.

Comment: You should not have to add too many JS files: you can customize your download of jQueryUI to only include the necessary ones: http://jqueryui.com/download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer

[JQuery Slider alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693721/jquery-slider-alternative)

Uses this slider

http://programming.arantius.com/lightweight+javascript+slider+control

Comment: Why not vote to close the question as a dupicate rather than answering and duplicating information on here.

Comment: because I dont have the option to vote for close (due to rep), and if it got closed, the person asking the question wont know the answer!

Comment: If it got closed, there'd be a link at the top, pointing them to the question it was closed as a duplicate of. If even *one* person votes to close, a comment is posted that contains the link to the proposed duplicate. If you don't have adequate rep to vote to close, please leave such a **comment** yourself, and someone else who happens along with the requisite rep will vote to close.